# Getting TypeError: _ is undefined when trying to access data that comes from an API

Tags: reactjs

I use this useState hook to store a JSON array inside it.

```
const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);
```

I fetch the data from an API through this useEffect hook

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchPokemonData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const pokemonDetails = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${match.params.id}`);
        setPokemon(pokemonDetails.data);
        setLoading(false);
    };
    
    fetchPokemonData();
}, [match])
```

then I try to display a piece of data through this

```
<section id="pokemon-info" className="bg-info text-center px-5 col-md-12 col-lg-6 flex-fill">
            <h1>{pokemon.name}({pokemon.names[0].name})</h1></section>
```

It works sometimes but other times, I get the error

```
TypeError: pokemon.names is undefined
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the data not being loaded in yet.
I get the data from this API endpoint https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/

Comment: Add a try-catch in the async function.

Comment: I have tried adding a try catch function and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was pokemon.names was still undefined when React is trying to render the component, thus, giving the error. This happens for any object array that was included by the API when fetching the data. I solved the problem by first checking whether or not the data is accessible. So,

```
<h1>{pokemon.name}({pokemon.names[0].name})</h1>
```

becomes

```
<h1>{pokemon.name}({pokemon.names && pokemon.names[0].name})</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Pokemons are inside `pokemon.data.results`.

Check this example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);

  const fetchPokemonData = async () => {
    const pokemonDetails = await axios.get(
      `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/`
    );
    setPokemon(pokemonDetails.data.results[0].name);
    console.log(pokemonDetails.data.results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPokemonData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <section
          id="pokemon-info"
          className="bg-info text-center px-5 col-md-12 col-lg-6 flex-fill"
        >
          <h1>{pokemon}</h1>
        </section>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and that didn't fix it unfortunately.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was bad. What I'm doing is I'm getting a specific pokemon by adding their id number in the url. I don't have the results when I fetch from the API.